# Flex container dropdown navigation, pushes content when expanded

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a fiddle below. The first dropdown menu is using a [Flexible Box Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/). I was trying to replace the second menu below which is composed of floats.

Afaik floating content brings it out of the usual "flow" and that is why my floated example looks better. My goal is to use the [flexible box layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/) to accomplish something similar to the floated nav. I don't want the content pushed down when hovering the menu. I would like it to overlap like the floated example. I guess the bottomline is, i dont want the Flex container to expand to encompass the full height of the hovered menu.

How can i accomplish this? Thank you for any input regarding this.

http://jsfiddle.net/hRKgV/

I've only added the webkit syntax but the fiddle seems to work in all major browsers (guess it's due to how fiddle works).

If it helps anyone else (which i doubt) it can almost be accomplished by adding this:

```
#flexmenu ul{    
float:left;
width:100%;
}

#content{
clear:both;
}
```

Of course, The reason why im trying this new model is not having to use the other workarounds. Hope this helps see what i would like accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand but I'm gonna take a guess. Menus that overlap content without pushing it? You'd want to use classes and not IDs. Something like this: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hRKgV/)

```
#content, #content2 {
background-color:#AABBCC;
    clear:both;
}

.floatedmenu {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.floatedmenu ul {
    clear:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
}

.floatedmenu ul li {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
}

.floatedmenu ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:auto;
}

.floatedmenu ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.floatedmenu ul ul li {
    left:auto;
    margin:0;
    clear:left;
    width:100%;
}

.floatedmenu ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin: 2px;
    z-index: 2;
}
​
```

Comment: The floatedmenu in the example already "overlaps" the content. That is to say, the "menu" links are placed on top of content2 hiding it slightly. I would like to do the same using the flexible box layout model (first menu). I tried adding the z-index but it didn't seem to help. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm sorry. I personally think that some javascript is your best bet to get what you're looking for.